# Where do I keep track of sorcery points on a character sheet?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, class-feature, sorcerer, character-sheets

I’m a little confused about the sorcery point system, mainly where I keep track of them on my character sheet.

Should I keep track in the “attacks and spellcasting” box, or is there somewhere else I should put them in particular?

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19692/how-to-track-character-resources-spells-ammo-items/19742#19742

Answer (score 16):

## That depends on the character sheet you are using.

There are class-specific character sheets on [DMs Guild](https://www.dmsguild.com), see [here](https://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?keywords=sorcerer+sheet). These generally have a dedicated box for sorcery points.

If you use [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com), you can find sorcery point boxes in the 'Features & Traits' tab under 'Class Features'.

On [Roll20](https://wiki.roll20.net/5th_Edition_OGL_by_Roll20),
there's a section on the right side of the character sheet for [counters for resources from your class or other sources](https://wiki.roll20.net/5th_Edition_OGL_by_Roll20#.2813.29_Class_.26_Other_Resources), as noted in a comment by V2Blast.

Finally, if you use a generic sheet or just a piece of notepaper, you can record the sorcery points on any place convenient for you. As you are the main and usually only user of you character sheet, it mainly needs to make sense to you yourself.

Answer (score 7):

[Mala's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/152938/23970) is completely correct in pointing out that the standard locations vary, and where they are for some common sources of charsheet.

I'll add in my experience: no printed character sheet (I still use dead trees) has ever had what I consider a good place for sorcery points, ki points, maneuver dice, even spell slots. I'm going to be using these resources every combat: I want them near my HP, AC, attack modifiers, &c. Front-and-center.

My solution: on the front page of whatever sheet we're looking at, somewhere central, I take a fine-tipped black Sharpie marker and draw some small boxes. I label them "Sorcery pts (LR)" or "Ki (SR)" or "Rage (LR)" or whatever. Then, in play, when I've used one I can put a little penciled checkmark in the box; when the appropriate rest has passed I can erase the whole area. When I level up, I can add a box to the row.

Comment: nitsua, you may want to check out the More Purple More Better character sheets, which has a section for limited features (resets on LR, SR, Dawn, Day) front and centre. http://www.enworld.org/forum/rpgdownloads.php?do=download&downloadid=1180

Comment: The printer friendly redesign in particular

Comment: @illustro I love MPMB! I like how they put the "rechargable" class features front&center (and their actions/bonus actions/reactions section!)--the only thing I like even better is having little tick-boxes rather than MPMB's default "ki points // 5 // SR" tabular notation. So I print my MPMBs and draw little tick-boxes on them =)